# 基本情報技術者試験『タブ文字を展開するプログラム』の解答を知りたい

Tags: アルゴリズム

以下の問題のaにはどの選択肢が当てはまるのでしょうか？
どなたか解答を教えてくださいませ。

---

[タブ文字を展開するプログラム | 基本情報技術者試験 過去問](https://jpeducom.co.jp/FE18b-pm/t04.html)

副プログラム TabSpc は、タブ文字を展開するプログラムである。

1. TabSpc は、引数で指定された文字型配列 Src[] を先頭から調べ、 Src[]
   中のすべてのタブ文字をそれぞれ一つ以上の間隔文字（スペース）に変換して、
   引数で指定された文字型配列 Dst[] に格納する。
2. 文字型配列の各要素には、文字を 1 文字ずつ順に格納し、最後の文字の次の
   要素にはシステム定数である EOS を格納する。なお、配列の添字は 1 から始
   まり、添字の値を文字位置と呼ぶ。
3. Src[] 中にタブ文字が出現した場合、次の文字が最も近い右のタブ位置に格納
   されるように、タブ文字を一つ以上の間隔文字に置換して、 Dst[] （要素数は十
   分に大きいとする）に格納する。ここで、タブ位置とは、整数型の引数 TabGap で
   渡されるタブ間隔（≧ 2）を用いて、次の式で計算される文字位置である。
   タブ位置 ＝ タブ間隔 × n + 1 （ n は 1 以上の整数）
4. タブ間隔が 4 のときの実行例を図に示す。 “j” を Dst[] のタブ位置である文
   字位置 13 （ = 4 × 3 + 1 ）に格納したのでは、タブ文字が間隔文字に置き換
   わらないので、最も近い右のタブ位置である文字位置 17 （ = 4 × 4 + 1 ）に
   格納する。

[image]

［プログラム］

```
○TabSpc(文字型：Src[], 文字型：Dst[], 整数型：TabGap)
○整数型：Sidx, Didx, N, TabPos
・Sidx ← 1
・Didx ← 1
■ Src[Sidx] ≠ EOS /* EOS：文字列の終わりを表すシステム定数 */
| ▲ Src[Sidx] = TAB /* TAB：タブ文字を表すシステム定数 */
| | ・N ← ( a ) ÷ TabGap
| | ・TabPos ← TabGap × N + 1
| | ■ Didx ＜ TabPos
| | | ・Dst[Didx] ← SPC /* SPC：間隔文字を表すシステム定数 */
| | | ・ b
| | ■
| +---
| | ・ c
| | ・Didx ← Didx + 1
| ▼
| ・Sidx ← Sidx + 1
■
・Dst[Didx] ← EOS
```

**設問** プログラム中のに入れる正しい答えを、解答群の中から選べ。
a に関する解答群
ア Didx + 1
イ Didx – 1
ウ Didx + TabGap + 1
エ Didx + TabGap – 1

Comment: 解答を知りたいだけならそのページの「 解答 a 」をクリックすればよいかと思いますよ。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！設問を書き写す労力は大変だったと思いますが、ご質問の回答は「エです」で完結します。そして基本情報技術者試験は問題文をWeb検索することや問題集を購入することで[平成18年秋期基本情報技術者試験午後問4、疑似言語](https://ai-light.org/blog-entry-310.html)のように解答と解説を得ることができます。解説を読んでも分からない点や納得できない点を詳細に記述していただくとピンポイントに求めている回答を得やすくなりますので、ぜひご自身の悩んでいる部分を説明できるように質問文を編集してみてください！

Comment: 解答を知りたいのですが、問題しかもってないので困っています。どなたか解答わかる方教えてください。

Comment: payanecoさん、解答ありがとうございます。エが正解なのですね。また色々なアドバイスありがとうございます。ぜひこれから参考にさせていただきたいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82294/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0%e3%81%ab%e9%96%a2%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e8%a7%a3%e7%ad%94%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84#comment92979_82294)で解決したので回答に転記します。

> 答えは『エ』です。

上をクリックやタップすると解答が表示されます。

蛇足ですが、この回答時点では質問文の画像URLをたどって[問題文と回答](https://jpeducom.co.jp/FE18b-pm/t04.html)を参照することもできます。